# Replace string matching to $JAVA_HOME in $PATH

Tags: awk, path, grep, gsub, java-home

I have a script that switches Java version in RHEL using `alternatives --set java`. However, I cannot export `JAVA_HOME`, `CLASSPATH`, or `PATH` from the same script for their use in the calling shell outside of the script. After calling the script, I need to `source .bashrc` which has the following.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink $(readlink $(which javac)))))
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Here's the output I get at the prompt:

```
# $PATH
[tahamed@localhost ~]$ echo $PATH
/home/tahamed/.local/bin:/home/tahamed/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.10.0.7-2.el9.x86_64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.10.0.7-2.el9.x86_64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.10.0.7-2.el9.x86_64/bin

# $JAVA_HOME
[tahamed@localhost ~]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-21.0.2.0.13-1.el9.x86_64
```

The `export PATH` in it's current form will only append the new `$JAVA_HOME/bin` but what I really want to do is replace all occurrences of the substring matching `$JAVA_HOME` in the `PATH` before exporting.

I explored the following but getting "unterminated regexp" error on ']' in grep.

```
echo $PATH | awk '{gsub(/java-[^\/]*/, $(echo $JAVA_HOME | grep -o 'java-[^\/]*'))} 1'
```

```
[tahamed@localhost ~]$ echo $PATH | awk '{gsub(/java-[^\/]*/, $(echo $JAVA_HOME | grep -o 'java-[^\/]*'))} 1'
awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(/java-[^\/]*/, $(echo $JAVA_HOME | grep -o java-[^/]*))} 1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                          ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(/java-[^\/]*/, $(echo $JAVA_HOME | grep -o java-[^/]*))} 1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(/java-[^\/]*/, $(echo $JAVA_HOME | grep -o java-[^/]*))} 1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                          ^ unterminated regexp
```

`grep` works when run individually:

```
[tahamed@localhost ~]$ echo $JAVA_HOME | grep -o 'java-[^\/]*'
java-21-openjdk-21.0.2.0.13-1.el9.x86_64
```

When the above would work, I intend to update `export PATH=...` in `.bashrc` with the following.

```
export PATH=$(echo $PATH | awk '{gsub(/java-[^\/]*/, $(echo $JAVA_HOME | grep -o 'java-[^\/]*'))} 1'))
```

Comment: Can you simplify (this mess) by a simple example of input/expected output?

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you trying to modify your .bashrc or extract parts of some variables or do something else? Please [edit] your question to provide clear sample input and expected output and state what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I believe he wants to re-source his `.bashrc` to update his PATH variable after switching to an alternate Java version through the `alternatives --set` system (which symlinks `/usr/bin/java` --> `/etc/alternatives/java` --> `/usr/lib/jvm/SOME_JKK_VERSION...` if I remember correctly). Sourcing keeps appending ":$JAVA_HOME/bin" so he probably wants to _replace_ any potential occurrence(s) of "/usr/lib/jvm/java-..." with the latest symlinked version.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.bashrc`, instead of using `awk`, you could resort to a few simple Unix commands like :

```
printf '%s' "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | grep -Fv '/java-' | paste -s -d ':'
```

So your `export` statements would look like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink $(readlink $(which javac)))))"
export CLASSPATH=".:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export PATH="$(printf '%s' "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | grep -Fv '/java-' | paste -s -d ':'):$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why would you replace 1 call to awk with 3 pipes and calls to 3 separate commands though?

Comment: You could probably use SED (something like `printf '%s' "$PATH" | sed -e 's/[^:]*java-[^:]*:*//g' -e 's/:*$//'`) or AWK. Can't think of a simple solution using the latter, though ...

Comment: The implementation of that sed script in awk would be `awk '{gsub(/[^:]*java-[^:]*:*/,""); sub(/:*$/,"")} 1'` but there may be a more idiomatic solution to the OPs problem, we just don't know what that problem is yet.